# Is there an add-on to auto compress files while uploading into Plone?

Tags: python, plone

Is there any add-on which will activate while uploading files into the Plone site automatically? It should compress the files and then upload into the files. These can be image files like CAD drawings or any other types. Irrespective of the file type, beyond a specific size, they should get compressed and stored, rather than manually compressing the files and storing them.I am using plone 4.1. I am aware of the css, javascript files which get compressed, but not of uploaded files. I am also aware of the 'image handling' in the 'Site Setup'

Comment: there is no such add-on but it should be fairly easy to implement with some subclassing

Comment: @Maulwurfn is there some guide where you meant 'subclassing'? Thx in advance

Comment: this is a task for an experienced programmer with object-oriented skills and a reasonable background in Plone programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Maulwurfn says, there is no such add-on, but this would be fairly straightforward for an experienced developer to implementing using a custom content type.  You will want to be pretty sure that the specific file types you're hoping to store will actually benefit from compression (many modern file formats already include some compression, and so simply zipping them won't shrink them much).

Also, unless you implement something complex like a client-side Flash uploader with built-in compression, Plone can only compress files *after* they've been uploaded, not before, so if you're hoping to make uploads quicker for users, rather than to minimize storage space, you're facing a somewhat more difficult challenge.

Comment: In fact if you do not need to support legacy browsers you can perform the compression on the client side using Javascript, Web workers and HTML5 apis. I am already doing client side image resizes before uploading.

Comment: Sweet!  I'd love to see that in an add-on.